# How to solve circular import problem in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am having a circular important problem and the only workaround I am able to come up with is to move the import statement from the top of the module to the place where it's needed like this:

```py
def serialize_message(message):
    from chat.serializers import MessageSerializer

    serializer = MessageSerializer(
        {
            'pk': message.id,
            'when': message.created_at,
            'conversation': message.conversation.id,
            'object': message
        }
    )

    return serializer.data
```

This is working fine, but I want to know if this is a safe thing to do?

Comment: Yes. What would you consider unsafe behaviour about this?

Comment: Importing a module within a function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) is a regular statement and can be used anywhere a statement is allowed, including `def` and `class` bodies. It has the same behaviour at global, function and class scope: the module is loaded if necessary, and the requested names are bound in the current scope.

This also means that under normal conditions, a module is loaded only once. Repeatedly calling a function with an `import` statement will not reload the module each time but use the previously loaded module instance.

---

The only restriction is that dynamic name binding is not allowed in function and class scope. As such, a `*` import is not allowed. This is guaranteed to be rejected before running the code.

> The wild card form of import — `from module import *` — is only allowed at the module level. Attempting to use it in class or function definitions will raise a `SyntaxError`.